# Getting dynamic field data using vue.js in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I am creating multiple dynamic fields and the same is posted to the laravel controller methods but i'm able to get the simple fields data (fields that are not dynamically generated) but the array fields that are dynamically generated those values i'm unable to get in the controller method.

```
 <input :name="'students['+studentdetails.id+']['+studentdetails.class+']'" type="text" class="form-control"/>
 <input :name="'students['+studentdetails.id+']['+studentdetails.class+']'" type="text" class="form-control"/>
```

In my controller method when i'm getting it:

```
  printr($request->attributes);


 export default {
  data() {
...

return {
      
      form: new Form({
        title: "",
        attributes: [],
        }),
   };

  addStudent() {
          const header = {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
          };
          this.form
            .post(APP_URL + `/api/addStudent`, { headers: header })
            .then((response) => {
              if (response.status == 200) {
                location.replace(APP_URL + "/success");
              } 
            });
        },
};
```

there is not value.

Answer (score 0):

You are now creating `[]` and `students` as strings, and they should not be. Remove the string quotes completely, as you are using variables only:

```
:name="students[studentdetails.id][studentdetails.class]"
```